# What are these favicon-like icons called in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, icons, favicon

I just noticed some icons on the right side of the url in Chrome (on a Mac) with favicons of technologies used by the current website.

[image: Favicons for site technology]

Clicking on the single icon shows a dropdown/tooltip with software used by the site, such as nginx, WordPress, php, and others. You can click on the icons in the dropdown to open a new tab/window to the homepage for that technology (ex nginx.com).

What are these icons called? And how does Chrome know what the site is using? As a website developer, these are not explicitly defined in my page, yet they show up, so it must be some header detection or something. It would also be nice to know if they can be modified, suppressed, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just noticed some icons on the right side of the url in Chrome (on a Mac) with favicons of technologies used by the current website.

Looks like the work done by the ["AppSpector" extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/homgcnaoacgigpkkljjjekpignblkeae) (also see the extension author's [page about AppSpector](http://www.nqbao.com/blog/appspector/)).

[image: AppSpector Icons]

> What are these icons called?

The icons in this scenario have no specific name, they are just icons added by the extension to represent the technologies it finds.

> how does Chrome know what the site is using?

The extension detects what's used by checking for common libraries required for the various web/tech stacks, as well as checking header information to determine web server make, etc.

> This extension will help web developer to inspect web framework / CMS
>   and javascript library running on current browsing website. An icon
>   will appear on address bar indicates the detected framework. Version
>   detecting is being implemented.
>
> Currently, this extension can detect more than 100 popular CMS and
>   javascript libraries, and more will be added in future releases. Visit
>   extension website for more detail.

.

> It would also be nice to know if they can be modified, suppressed, etc.

This is a client-side detection, the only way you could prevent it on machine that are not yours (as a website creator), is to not use libraries it recognizes.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was native to Chrome. The screenshot was from a coworker, which explains why I didn't see it on my computer (I initially thought it was because I'm on Linux).